# Visual studio issue in new project dialog

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

In new project dialog 'Ok' button is missing to add new project.[image]

Comment: Strange, looks like the entire internal area of the dialog is shifted down and to the right. Are you using some accessibility settings or running this in a VM?

Comment: Btw, In screenshot it is seen that you are using VS2013 then why did you tag vs2010 and vs2012 instead of vs2013 ?

Comment: No,  I am not using vm. it was working 1 month before,  click is also not working properly  if I clicked on wpf application template it will be focused on console application.

Comment: I have reinstalled  entire VS2013. but issue is same.

Comment: I am using windows 10 build-10122

Comment: Can you try changing the location you are willing to create your project? I assume it maybe related to write permission

Comment: Another idea if my first comment won't help. try reset your vs setting  from the import and export setting menu.

Comment: No, Infect inner-area of all dialog in vs2013 is shifted down. Not only new project.

Comment: I have a doubt update of windows 10 beta  has created this issue.

Comment: @DeJaVo  done reset. not fixed yet.

Comment: Have you changed the Windows Font Scaling or DPI settings? Dialog developers are known to not take that into account within the dialog UI.